# Doctrine: executeQuery() adds extra values in return

Tags: doctrine, silex

When I run the query below:

```
$where = array(
    $request->get("order_item_id"), //an array with integers
);
$types = array(
    \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY
);

$sql = "SELECT id,store_id FROM order_items WHERE id IN (?) ORDER BY id";
$query = $app['db']->executeQuery($sql, $where, $types);
$order_items = $query->fetchAll();
```

I get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [store_id] => 11
            [1] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [0] => 6
            [store_id] => 11
            [1] => 11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [0] => 11
            [store_id] => 11
            [1] => 11
        )
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the extra 0 and 1 vals returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$order_items = $query->fetchAssoc();
```

for one row return with only field names.

or try passing in PDO::FETCH_ASSOC to fetchAll() function.

Comment: That did it! Thank you: $order_items = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);